# React MUI Accordion always open one

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionDetails,
  AccordionSummary,
  Typography
} from "@mui/material";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

export default function DetailedAccordion() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event, isExpanded) => {
    setExpanded(isExpanded ? panel : false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion defaultExpanded
        expanded={expanded === "panel1"}
        onChange={handleChange("panel1")}
      >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
          id="panel1bh-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion Panel 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae
            elit libero, a pharetra augue.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion
        expanded={expanded === "panel2"}
        onChange={handleChange("panel2")}
      >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
          id="panel2bh-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion Panel 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae
            elit libero, a pharetra augue.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion
        expanded={expanded === "panel3"}
        onChange={handleChange("panel3")}
      >
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3bh-content"
          id="panel3bh-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion Panel 3</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae
            elit libero, a pharetra augue.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want all panels to be non-closable. One should always remain open.

Tried the code above but somehow again I can close them all.
Whichever one I leave open I can't close until a new one opens.
All of them are closing on me all the time. One must be open.
Someone help how to solve this.
Here is a demo here. [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-snowflake-ys20oj?file=/demo.js:0-2222)

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to store the state of each accordion in the state of the component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  Accordion,
  AccordionDetails,
  AccordionSummary,
  Typography
} from "@mui/material";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore";

export default function DetailedAccordion() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState({
    panel1: true,
    panel2: false,
    panel3: false
  });

  const handleChange = (panel) => (event) => {
    if (panel === "panel1") {
      setExpanded({ panel1: true, panel2: false, panel3: false });
    }
    if (panel === "panel2") {
      setExpanded({ panel1: false, panel2: true, panel3: false });
    }
    if (panel === "panel3") {
      setExpanded({ panel1: false, panel2: false, panel3: true });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion expanded={expanded.panel1} onChange={handleChange("panel1")}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel1bh-content"
          id="panel1bh-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion Panel 1</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae
            elit libero, a pharetra augue.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion expanded={expanded.panel2} onChange={handleChange("panel2")}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel2bh-content"
          id="panel2bh-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion Panel 2</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae
            elit libero, a pharetra augue.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
      <Accordion expanded={expanded.panel3} onChange={handleChange("panel3")}>
        <AccordionSummary
          expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
          aria-controls="panel3bh-content"
          id="panel3bh-header"
        >
          <Typography>Accordion Panel 3</Typography>
        </AccordionSummary>
        <AccordionDetails>
          <Typography>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla vitae
            elit libero, a pharetra augue.
          </Typography>
        </AccordionDetails>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?  [CodeSandbox Example Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-accordion-only-one-open-panel-6z8xkx?file=/src/App.js)

```
const panelInfo = [
  { name: "Accordion Panel 1", details: "Accordion Panel 1 details..." },
  { name: "Accordion Panel 2", details: "Accordion Panel 2 details..." },
  { name: "Accordion Panel 3", details: "Accordion Panel 3 details..." }
];

export default function App() {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = useState(panelInfo[0]);

  function handleAccordClick(panel) {
    if (expanded !== panel) setExpanded(panel);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {panelInfo.map((panel) => (
        <Accordion
          expanded={panel === expanded}
          onClick={() => handleAccordClick(panel)}
          key={panel}
        >
          <AccordionSummary>{panel.name}</AccordionSummary>
          <AccordionDetails>{panel.details}</AccordionDetails>
        </Accordion>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```